# I can not change the author of the material, an error occurs. error code inside, along with a screenshot

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to change the author of the material, but the Ajax work with error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX path used for autocompleting usernames (**user/autocomplete**) [requires](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/user/user.module?h=7.50#n1635) a user to have the *access user profiles* permission:

```
  $items['user/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'User autocomplete',
    'page callback' => 'user_autocomplete',
    'access callback' => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );
```

Make sure that is true for the user account that's entering the data into the autocomplete field.

If the account does have the permission then the problem is specific to your environment (e.g. a module that alters `access callback` / `access arguments` of router item) and requires further debugging that falls out of the scope here.

Comment: I logged into the site as the Super User

Comment: Something else is triggering the 403 then, you'll need to do further debugging to find out the root cause.